# 2dDensity facet scale

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2, density-plot

I am making 2d Density graphs with some tracking data.

**My goal is to make plots for each experimental unit**

My df looks like this:

```
head(df)
  Caja  x  y          t
1    4  0  0 0:00:00:00
2    4 -2 10 0:00:00:14
3    4  3 26 0:00:00:28
4    4  7 54 0:00:00:42
5    4  9 75 0:00:00:57
6    4  9 92 0:00:00:71
```

The first column (Caja) is the factor I use for faceting (because each level is a different experimental unit). `x` and `y` are the variables I am interested in, t is just the time in which the measure was taken.

Since `df` is a long data.frane and I am going to use `caja4` later I provide it

```
dput(caja4)
structure(list(Caja = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), x = c(0L, -2L, 
3L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 11L, 6L, -12L, -23L, -33L, -32L, -36L, -28L, 
-15L, -2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 0L, -1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 
11L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 12L, 0L, 3L, 10L, 5L, -14L, -10L, 5L, 10L, 
12L, 12L, 11L, 11L, 9L, 9L, 11L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 7L, 1L, -6L, 
-11L, -18L, -25L, -17L, -7L, -2L, -5L, -4L, -24L, -29L, -37L, 
-39L, -41L, -41L, -41L, -41L, -41L, -41L, -41L, -39L, -39L, -39L, 
-39L, -39L, -39L, -39L, -39L, -39L, -28L, -17L, -11L, -6L, -9L, 
-16L, -27L, -37L, -38L, -42L, -42L, -42L, -42L, -42L, -42L, -42L, 
-42L, -42L, -42L, -36L, -28L, -17L, -6L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, -2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, -1L, -1L, -9L, 
-12L, -30L, -38L, -37L, -36L, -42L, -42L, -42L, -42L, -42L, -43L, 
-43L, -43L, -36L, -35L, -29L, -26L, -29L, -37L, -38L, -38L, -38L, 
-37L, -31L, -18L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 10L, 13L, 
12L, -13L, -32L, -41L, -31L, -14L, 0L, 10L, 2L, -8L, -29L, -37L, 
-37L, -37L, -37L, -37L, -37L, -37L, -28L, -14L, -3L, 4L, 3L, 
1L, -7L, -15L, -11L, -11L, -15L, -16L, -27L, -37L, -43L, -43L, 
-43L, -43L, -43L, -43L, -43L, -24L, -1L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 4L, -9L, -31L, -45L, -45L, -34L, -32L, -4L, -12L, -8L, 
-6L, -17L, -31L, -36L, -42L, -37L, -39L, -36L, -36L, -36L, -37L, 
-37L, -36L, -37L, -32L, -19L, -5L, 2L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 10L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 12L, -1L, -14L, -32L, -17L, 
-2L, -14L, -26L, -44L, -44L, -44L, -44L, -44L, -44L, -45L, -45L, 
-33L, -21L, -12L, -11L, -5L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, -7L, -29L, -27L, -10L, -2L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 13L), 
    y = c(0L, 10L, 26L, 54L, 75L, 92L, 113L, 116L, 117L, 114L, 
    119L, 115L, 114L, 108L, 99L, 90L, 76L, 57L, 37L, 21L, 12L, 
    7L, 8L, 2L, -2L, 5L, 7L, 17L, 37L, 52L, 67L, 86L, 100L, 118L, 
    122L, 125L, 122L, 122L, 129L, 129L, 126L, 124L, 125L, 123L, 
    106L, 92L, 70L, 49L, 27L, 17L, 5L, 6L, 10L, 7L, 3L, -3L, 
    -3L, -6L, -8L, -13L, -13L, -14L, -13L, -13L, -5L, 1L, 3L, 
    7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 25L, 42L, 44L, 57L, 87L, 101L, 107L, 110L, 
    102L, 96L, 94L, 81L, 68L, 57L, 50L, 61L, 76L, 96L, 97L, 96L, 
    98L, 99L, 95L, 79L, 64L, 53L, 46L, 31L, 12L, 4L, -7L, -16L, 
    -17L, -17L, -17L, -17L, -17L, -17L, -16L, -17L, -17L, -17L, 
    -17L, -17L, -17L, -17L, -17L, -6L, 15L, 31L, 50L, 71L, 95L, 
    105L, 119L, 125L, 119L, 117L, 116L, 127L, 112L, 94L, 77L, 
    55L, 26L, 0L, -1L, -2L, 1L, -4L, -5L, -5L, -6L, -10L, -11L, 
    -11L, -11L, -10L, -9L, -10L, -8L, 4L, 9L, 15L, 25L, 41L, 
    57L, 71L, 84L, 100L, 117L, 133L, 134L, 137L, 134L, 134L, 
    135L, 139L, 135L, 131L, 120L, 125L, 132L, 131L, 127L, 140L, 
    143L, 144L, 143L, 143L, 142L, 139L, 138L, 131L, 124L, 104L, 
    80L, 61L, 45L, 23L, 9L, -4L, -4L, -8L, -13L, -13L, -13L, 
    -13L, -13L, -13L, -13L, -10L, -2L, 0L, 7L, 24L, 36L, 56L, 
    77L, 108L, 123L, 137L, 139L, 129L, 130L, 117L, 128L, 123L, 
    117L, 126L, 125L, 124L, 145L, 145L, 107L, 104L, 92L, 83L, 
    75L, 62L, 47L, 32L, 17L, 1L, -7L, -8L, -10L, -8L, -5L, -6L, 
    -3L, -1L, 10L, 20L, 28L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 52L, 74L, 98L, 114L, 
    116L, 116L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 120L, 117L, 114L, 107L, 109L, 
    87L, 69L, 37L, 12L, 8L, -14L, -14L, -14L, -11L, 2L, 17L, 
    29L, 25L, 12L, -9L, 0L, 12L, 28L, 54L, 84L, 96L, 105L, 114L, 
    114L, 111L, 112L, 111L, 116L, 120L, 120L, 127L), t = structure(1:294, .Label = c("0:00:00:00", 
    "0:00:00:14", "0:00:00:28", "0:00:00:42", "0:00:00:57", "0:00:00:71", 
    "0:00:00:85", "0:00:01:00", "0:00:01:14", "0:00:01:28", "0:00:01:42", 
    "0:00:01:57", "0:00:01:71", "0:00:01:85", "0:00:02:00", "0:00:02:14", 
    "0:00:02:28", "0:00:02:42", "0:00:02:57", "0:00:02:71", "0:00:02:85", 
    "0:00:03:00", "0:00:03:14", "0:00:03:28", "0:00:03:42", "0:00:03:57", 
    "0:00:03:71", "0:00:03:85", "0:00:04:00", "0:00:04:14", "0:00:04:28", 
    "0:00:04:42", "0:00:04:57", "0:00:04:71", "0:00:04:85", "0:00:05:00", 
    "0:00:05:14", "0:00:05:28", "0:00:05:42", "0:00:05:57", "0:00:05:71", 
    "0:00:05:85", "0:00:06:00", "0:00:06:14", "0:00:06:28", "0:00:06:42", 
    "0:00:06:57", "0:00:06:71", "0:00:06:85", "0:00:07:00", "0:00:07:14", 
    "0:00:07:28", "0:00:07:42", "0:00:07:57", "0:00:07:71", "0:00:07:85", 
    "0:00:08:00", "0:00:08:14", "0:00:08:28", "0:00:08:42", "0:00:08:57", 
    "0:00:08:71", "0:00:08:85", "0:00:09:00", "0:00:09:14", "0:00:09:28", 
    "0:00:09:42", "0:00:09:57", "0:00:09:71", "0:00:09:85", "0:00:10:00", 
    "0:00:10:14", "0:00:10:28", "0:00:10:42", "0:00:10:57", "0:00:10:71", 
    "0:00:10:85", "0:00:11:00", "0:00:11:14", "0:00:11:28", "0:00:11:42", 
    "0:00:11:57", "0:00:11:71", "0:00:11:85", "0:00:12:00", "0:00:12:14", 
    "0:00:12:28", "0:00:12:42", "0:00:12:57", "0:00:12:71", "0:00:12:85", 
    "0:00:13:00", "0:00:13:14", "0:00:13:28", "0:00:13:42", "0:00:13:57", 
    "0:00:13:71", "0:00:13:85", "0:00:14:00", "0:00:14:14", "0:00:14:28", 
    "0:00:14:42", "0:00:14:57", "0:00:14:71", "0:00:14:85", "0:00:15:00", 
    "0:00:15:14", "0:00:15:28", "0:00:15:42", "0:00:15:57", "0:00:15:71", 
    "0:00:15:85", "0:00:16:00", "0:00:16:14", "0:00:16:28", "0:00:16:42", 
    "0:00:16:57", "0:00:16:71", "0:00:16:85", "0:00:17:00", "0:00:17:14", 
    "0:00:17:28", "0:00:17:42", "0:00:17:57", "0:00:17:71", "0:00:17:85", 
    "0:00:18:00", "0:00:18:14", "0:00:18:28", "0:00:18:42", "0:00:18:57", 
    "0:00:18:71", "0:00:18:85", "0:00:19:00", "0:00:19:14", "0:00:19:28", 
    "0:00:19:42", "0:00:19:57", "0:00:19:71", "0:00:19:85", "0:00:20:00", 
    "0:00:20:14", "0:00:20:28", "0:00:20:42", "0:00:20:57", "0:00:20:71", 
    "0:00:20:85", "0:00:21:00", "0:00:21:14", "0:00:21:28", "0:00:21:42", 
    "0:00:21:57", "0:00:21:71", "0:00:21:85", "0:00:22:00", "0:00:22:14", 
    "0:00:22:28", "0:00:22:42", "0:00:22:57", "0:00:22:71", "0:00:22:85", 
    "0:00:23:00", "0:00:23:14", "0:00:23:28", "0:00:23:42", "0:00:23:57", 
    "0:00:23:71", "0:00:23:85", "0:00:24:00", "0:00:24:14", "0:00:24:28", 
    "0:00:24:42", "0:00:24:57", "0:00:24:71", "0:00:24:85", "0:00:25:00", 
    "0:00:25:14", "0:00:25:28", "0:00:25:42", "0:00:25:57", "0:00:25:71", 
    "0:00:25:85", "0:00:26:00", "0:00:26:14", "0:00:26:28", "0:00:26:42", 
    "0:00:26:57", "0:00:26:71", "0:00:26:85", "0:00:27:00", "0:00:27:14", 
    "0:00:27:28", "0:00:27:42", "0:00:27:57", "0:00:27:71", "0:00:27:85", 
    "0:00:28:00", "0:00:28:14", "0:00:28:28", "0:00:28:42", "0:00:28:57", 
    "0:00:28:71", "0:00:28:85", "0:00:29:00", "0:00:29:14", "0:00:29:28", 
    "0:00:29:42", "0:00:29:57", "0:00:29:71", "0:00:29:85", "0:00:30:00", 
    "0:00:30:14", "0:00:30:28", "0:00:30:42", "0:00:30:57", "0:00:30:71", 
    "0:00:30:85", "0:00:31:00", "0:00:31:14", "0:00:31:28", "0:00:31:42", 
    "0:00:31:57", "0:00:31:71", "0:00:31:85", "0:00:32:00", "0:00:32:14", 
    "0:00:32:28", "0:00:32:42", "0:00:32:57", "0:00:32:71", "0:00:32:85", 
    "0:00:33:00", "0:00:33:14", "0:00:33:28", "0:00:33:42", "0:00:33:57", 
    "0:00:33:71", "0:00:33:85", "0:00:34:00", "0:00:34:14", "0:00:34:28", 
    "0:00:34:42", "0:00:34:57", "0:00:34:71", "0:00:34:85", "0:00:35:00", 
    "0:00:35:14", "0:00:35:28", "0:00:35:42", "0:00:35:57", "0:00:35:71", 
    "0:00:35:85", "0:00:36:00", "0:00:36:14", "0:00:36:28", "0:00:36:42", 
    "0:00:36:57", "0:00:36:71", "0:00:36:85", "0:00:37:00", "0:00:37:14", 
    "0:00:37:28", "0:00:37:42", "0:00:37:57", "0:00:37:71", "0:00:37:85", 
    "0:00:38:00", "0:00:38:14", "0:00:38:28", "0:00:38:42", "0:00:38:57", 
    "0:00:38:71", "0:00:38:85", "0:00:39:00", "0:00:39:14", "0:00:39:28", 
    "0:00:39:42", "0:00:39:57", "0:00:39:71", "0:00:39:85", "0:00:40:00", 
    "0:00:40:14", "0:00:40:28", "0:00:40:42", "0:00:40:57", "0:00:40:71", 
    "0:00:40:85", "0:00:41:00", "0:00:41:14", "0:00:41:28", "0:00:41:42", 
    "0:00:41:57", "0:00:41:71", "0:00:41:85"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Caja", 
"x", "y", "t"), row.names = c(NA, 294L), class = "data.frame")
```

For the plot I use

```
ggplot(data=df,aes(x,y)) + facet_wrap(~Caja) +
  stat_density2d(aes(fill=..level..,alpha=..level..),geom='polygon',colour='black') +
  scale_fill_continuous(low="green",high="red") +
  geom_point()+guides(alpha="none")
```

[image]

When I plot only `caja4` data

```
ggplot(data=caja4,aes(x,y)) + facet_wrap(~Caja) +
  stat_density2d(aes(fill=..level..,alpha=..level..),geom='polygon',colour='black') + 
  scale_fill_continuous(low="green",high="red") +
  geom_point()+guides(alpha="none")
```

[image]

This makes interpretation more easy although if you look at the line plot, things are a little bit different

```
ggplot(caja4,aes(x,y))+geom_point()+geom_path(col="red")+theme_classic()
```

[image]

I would like to have free density scale for the facets but have something that relies more to the line plot.

Comment: "I use base here because geom_line connects points in a wrong way and I don't know how to avoid that"...look into geom_path()

Comment: @MLavoie Thank you, I edited the post for ggplot only :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## General comments

Ok, a bunch of things to discuss here I think:

1. You can use `scales = 'free'` in your facet call to better align your plotting space with the data.
2. You cannot vary the density scale between facets. This is because the facets are generally meant to represent different groups using *common* aesthetically mappings. You could make separate figures instead, and stick them together (with for example the `cowplot` package).
3. The polygons get cut off in your plot, leaving you with a disappointing result. I would prefer to use `geom_tile` to visualize the density of points
4. As MLavoie pointed out, you'll want to use `geom_path` instead of `geom_line`.
5. That color scale is not so great. For example, it performs really poorly for colorblind people. I would recommend the `viridis` color scale (see below).
6. If the units for the `x` and `y` axis are the same and meaningful (cm, or pixels perhaps) you want to ensure they are represented in the same way. You can use `coord_equal()` for that.

## Making a nice plot for one trial

Here is some example code and a plot to combine this (I only have data for Caja 4):

```
library(viridis)

ggplot(caja4, aes(x,y)) +
  stat_density2d(geom = 'tile', aes(fill = ..density..), contour = FALSE) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_path() +
  scale_fill_viridis() +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

If you do want to use the contour polygons, you have to manually expand the axes to avoid clipping of the polygons ([or you have close the polygons yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28469829/how-to-fill-in-the-contour-fully-using-stat-contour)):

```
ggplot(caja4, aes(x,y)) +
  stat_density2d(geom = 'polygon', aes(fill = ..level..), contour = TRUE) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_path() +
  scale_fill_viridis() +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_minimal() +
  xlim(-60, 40) +
  ylim(-50, 170)
```

[image]

## Combining different trials

Instead of facets, we can use figure panels (see point 2 above). I find the `cowplot` package really useful for this. Below is some example code to easily create a composite figure. (*Note that I used `log(..density..)` here for a different scaling of the colors.*)

```
# Make data with three cajas (which only differ in x and y range here)
library(dplyr)

xy <- select(caja4, x, y)
cajas <- bind_rows('1' = xy, '2' = xy * 2, '3' = xy / 2, .id = 'Caja')

# Create ggplot objects for each caja
plots <- lapply(split(cajas, cajas$Caja),
                function(XX) {
                  plot = ggplot(XX, aes(x,y)) +
                    stat_density2d(geom = 'tile', aes(fill = log(..density..)), contour = FALSE) +
                    geom_point() + 
                    geom_path() +
                    scale_fill_viridis() +
                    coord_equal() +
                    theme_minimal()
                } )

plot_grid(plotlist = plots, nrow = 1, labels = 1:length(plots))
```

Which results in:

[image]

Comment: this is a great answer but still doesn't resolve the density scale problem I could upload the facet plot if you want

Comment: I am not sure,  would I need to make 8 plots (8 times the ggplot call into an object?) and then combine them with cowplot ?

Comment: Yes, I've added an example.