# Depth profile visual

Tags: ggplot2, data-visualization

Hi there I was wondering whether someone might assist with combining plots generated using the example provide on this page [Depth Profiling visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39798500/depth-profiling-visualization) where I have analyzed data for salinity and depth, however I have a categorical variable dividing three estuaries based on whether the mouth is "closed", "open", or "semi-closed". I used the code of Depth Profiling Visualization, however each plot has its own salinity legend scale per plot.

[image]

Here is the data.

```
     State Distance Depth   pH    DO       Chla Salinity Max.depth
```

1       Closed     0.60   0.0 8.66 10.64  0.8880000    18.49      -1.3
2       Closed     0.60   0.5 8.68 10.79  1.4800000    18.51      -1.3
3       Closed     0.60   1.3 8.73 11.26  1.1840000    18.51      -1.3
4       Closed     1.00   0.0 8.48  9.07  5.3280000    18.18      -0.8
5       Closed     1.00   0.8 8.47  8.30  2.9600000    18.35      -0.8
6       Closed     1.60   0.0 8.38  9.70  1.1840000    18.38      -2.0
7       Closed     1.60   0.5 8.40  9.33         NA    18.39      -2.0
8       Closed     1.60   1.0 8.40  9.27  1.1840000    18.39      -2.0
9       Closed     1.60   1.5 8.41  9.27         NA    18.41      -2.0
10      Closed     1.60   2.0 8.47  9.23  1.4800000    18.57      -2.0
11      Closed     2.15   0.0 8.40  9.85  2.6640000    18.26      -3.5
12      Closed     2.15   0.5 8.41  9.95         NA    18.27      -3.5
13      Closed     2.15   1.0 8.42  9.16  1.1840000    18.28      -3.5
14      Closed     2.15   2.0 8.42  9.82         NA    18.28      -3.5
15      Closed     2.15   3.5 8.38  9.17  0.5920000    18.30      -3.5
16      Closed     3.50   0.0 8.30  9.82  2.0720000    17.71      -5.0
17      Closed     3.50   0.5 8.31  9.78         NA    17.71      -5.0
18      Closed     3.50   1.0 8.32  9.75  1.4800000    17.72      -5.0
19      Closed     3.50   2.0 8.32  9.73         NA    17.78      -5.0
20      Closed     3.50   3.0 8.30  9.20         NA    17.95      -5.0
21      Closed     3.50   4.0 8.29  8.80         NA    18.00      -5.0
22      Closed     3.50   5.0 8.24  7.47  1.4800000    18.06      -5.0
23      Closed     4.85   0.0 8.21 10.10  2.9600000    17.33      -1.6
24      Closed     4.85   0.5 8.21  9.90  2.0720000    17.33      -1.6
25      Closed     4.85   1.0 8.21  9.73         NA    17.32      -1.6
26      Closed     4.85   1.6 8.22  9.60  1.1840000    17.32      -1.6
27      Closed     6.00   0.0 8.07  9.07  4.4400000    16.65      -1.5
28      Closed     6.00   0.5 8.06  8.98  5.6240000    16.65      -1.5
29      Closed     6.00   1.0 8.06  8.81         NA    16.67      -1.5
30      Closed     6.00   1.5 8.10  8.80  4.1440000    16.67      -1.5
31      Closed     6.70   0.0 7.83  9.25  0.0000000    13.90      -0.5
32        Open     0.60   0.0 7.56  8.42  1.1840000     1.62      -0.5
33        Open     0.60   0.5 7.62  8.40  1.9733333     1.79      -0.5
34        Open     1.00   0.0 7.67  8.55  1.1840000     1.10      -0.4
35        Open     1.00   0.4 7.62  8.49  1.5786667     1.10      -0.4
36        Open     1.60   0.0 7.48  8.40  1.5786667     0.98      -1.0
37        Open     1.60   0.5 7.47  8.33         NA     0.98      -1.0
38        Open     1.60   1.0 7.45  8.33  2.7626667     0.99      -1.0
39        Open     2.15   0.0 7.19  7.99  1.1840000     0.85      -1.0
40        Open     2.15   0.5 7.19  7.96         NA     0.86      -1.0
41        Open     2.15   1.0 7.18  7.98  1.1840000     0.89      -1.0
42        Open     3.50   0.0 7.14  7.56  0.3946667     0.55      -4.8
43        Open     3.50   0.5 7.20  7.50         NA     0.55      -4.8
44        Open     3.50   1.0 7.28  7.38  1.9733333     0.55      -4.8
45        Open     3.50   2.0 7.38  7.10         NA     0.55      -4.8
46        Open     3.50   3.0 7.56  6.15         NA     0.56      -4.8
47        Open     3.50   4.0 7.20  4.43         NA     2.65      -4.8
48        Open     3.50   4.8 6.93  2.25  1.9733333     6.76      -4.8
49        Open     4.85   0.0 6.90  8.29  1.1840000     0.26      -1.2
50        Open     4.85   0.5 6.77  8.20  0.7893333     0.27      -1.2
51        Open     4.85   1.2 6.55  8.20  0.7893333     0.39      -1.2
52        Open     6.00   0.0 6.49  9.53  1.1840000     0.13      -1.0
53        Open     6.00   0.5 6.59  9.53         NA     0.13      -1.0
54        Open     6.00   1.0 6.79  9.53  1.1840000     0.13      -1.0
55        Open     6.70   0.0 6.48  9.48  0.7893333     0.11      -0.5
56 Semi-closed     0.60   0.0 8.05  6.30 19.7300000    18.86      -1.4
57 Semi-closed     0.60   0.5 8.04  5.19 19.7300000    24.07      -1.4
58 Semi-closed     0.60   1.0 8.00  5.98         NA    30.50      -1.4
59 Semi-closed     0.60   1.4 7.87  6.19  5.1300000    31.18      -1.4
60 Semi-closed     1.00   0.0 7.99  5.75 22.8900000    18.81      -0.9
61 Semi-closed     1.00   0.5 7.95  5.10         NA    19.08      -0.9
62 Semi-closed     1.00   0.9 7.86  3.42 11.8400000    26.60      -0.9
63 Semi-closed     1.60   0.0 7.88  6.05 11.4500000    17.29      -1.7
64 Semi-closed     1.60   0.5 7.87  5.78         NA    17.32      -1.7
65 Semi-closed     1.60   1.0 7.86  4.74  8.6800000    17.44      -1.7
66 Semi-closed     1.60   1.5 7.84  3.90         NA    19.65      -1.7
67 Semi-closed     1.60   1.7 7.91  3.75  9.0800000    21.07      -1.7
68 Semi-closed     2.15   0.0 7.91  6.95 22.8900000    16.50      -1.3
69 Semi-closed     2.15   0.5 7.92  6.76 26.4400000    16.50      -1.3
70 Semi-closed     2.15   1.0 7.91  5.99         NA    17.40      -1.3
71 Semi-closed     2.15   1.3 7.97  4.10  7.1000000    18.79      -1.3
72 Semi-closed     3.50   0.0 7.75  6.13 18.5500000    15.86      -4.5
73 Semi-closed     3.50   0.5 7.72  5.90         NA    15.86      -4.5
74 Semi-closed     3.50   1.0 7.65  4.38  9.0800000    16.38      -4.5
75 Semi-closed     3.50   1.5 7.56  1.59         NA    20.09      -4.5
76 Semi-closed     3.50   2.0 7.55  0.38         NA    22.11      -4.5
77 Semi-closed     3.50   3.0 7.53  0.42         NA    30.36      -4.5
78 Semi-closed     3.50   4.0 7.52  0.52         NA    31.50      -4.5
79 Semi-closed     3.50   4.5 7.54  0.68  1.1800000    31.84      -4.5
80 Semi-closed     4.85   0.0 7.66  6.31 21.7100000    15.41      -1.6
81 Semi-closed     4.85   0.5 7.65  6.18         NA    15.44      -1.6
82 Semi-closed     4.85   1.0 7.65  5.57 21.3100000    15.54      -1.6
83 Semi-closed     4.85   1.6 7.52  0.76  6.7100000    22.60      -1.6
84 Semi-closed     6.00   0.0 7.74  8.50 87.6200000    13.11      -1.0
85 Semi-closed     6.00   0.5 7.66  7.38         NA    13.92      -1.0
86 Semi-closed     6.00   1.0 7.60  3.20  7.5000000    15.42      -1.0
87 Semi-closed     6.70   0.0 8.55  6.94  0.0000000     0.25      -0.5

I was hoping someone might be able to assist to unify the scales of the three legends from the three mouth conditions of estuary so that only one legend describing salinity for all plots is possible.

[image]

Comment: @cuttlefish44 can you help, this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: user:6384423 help

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput` instead of images?